# Sorting input in custom ordered-set aggregate function

Tags: postgresql

The initial problem is:
I want to aggregate some text field and produce an output similar to string_agg, but additionally line-wrapped at every N rows, like this:

```
 id |   f
----+--------
  1 | A,B,C,+
    | D,E,F
  2 | G,H,I,+
    | J,K,L
```

And as it is quite a boilerplate operation, I want a concise solution, so a custom aggregate function seems to fit best.

I want to control the number of elements between line breaks as well.
And this means there should be a direct argument to an aggregate function itself, which is only possible in Postgres with ordered-set aggregate functions IIUC.

So I've created a custom aggregate function (two clauses actually, first is a final function for the aggregate):

```
create function
    string_agg_wrap_ffunc (
        state text[], positions int
                         )
      returns text
language sql
begin atomic
    select
        regexp_replace (
            array_to_string (state, ','),
                     format ('(([^,]+,){%s})', positions),
                            e'\\1\n', 'g'
                       )
    ;
end
;


create aggregate
    string_agg_wrap(
               positions int
               order by text
                  ) (
               sfunc = array_append,
           finalfunc = string_agg_wrap_ffunc,
               stype = text[],
               initcond = '{}'
                    )
;
```

And it works fine, except one tiny detail: the input to the finalizing function is not sorted at all!

And I want it to be sorted as stated in a query where the function is used (not hard-coded in the finalizing function itself).

There is a vague passage in documentation, suggesting that there is actually no sort in such cases and functions should apply it themselves, getting ordering information from the AST node:

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/xaggr.html#XAGGR-SUPPORT-FUNCTIONS

> Another support routine available to aggregate functions written in C is AggGetAggref, which returns the Aggref parse node that defines the aggregate call. This is mainly useful for ordered-set aggregates, which can inspect the substructure of the Aggref node to find out what sort ordering they are supposed to implement.

But this does not apply to functions, written in SQL.

So am I correct, that this way to solve the problem is really at a dead end?

Is there any better way?

Comment: Why not create a function that turns a sorted array into multiple lines?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name thank You!

This is a valid solution, but if applied there might be multiple lines in each group in the query result with duplicate values in the grouping column, which are harder to manipulate in outer queries.

On second thought, creating a sorted array in an aggregate function (string_agg) and then feeding it to a custom non-aggregate function, which additionally chops it to chunks of needed length and then merges to one string with line breaks seems to be quite fine, though not one function operation =)